# Shape of the polar curve $r= \cos (\frac{15}{16}\theta)$ when the domain grows bigger and bigger.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Graph $r= \cos (\frac{15}{16}\theta)$, what pattern of the graph we will get and explain what happen if the domain grows bigger?

Comment: The function is periodic, so the graph is a closed curve. Can you check for self-intersections?

Answer (score 1):

This is from $0$ to $\pi$:[image]

Note that the ends don't connect.

This is from $0$ to $2\pi$:[image]

$0$ to $8\pi$:[image]

And it starts repeating after $32\pi$:[image]

Comment: Is this consider as a circle curve?

Comment: Depends on your definition of a "circle curve". I mean, it clearly isn't a circle...

Comment: What should I talk about this curve? Can you give some hints?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are expected to talk about. But I would observe that the pattern kind of rotates around the origin, and most importantly it is $32\pi$-periodic